# Switching Sitecore Indexing to Solr with SXA 1.4

Tags: sxa, solr

We have switched our Sitecore instance from Lucene to Solr with SXA 1.4.
Lucene works fine with the 'yyyyMMdd' date format but Solr needs 'yyyy-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ', so querying is not working when we filter on date.

The date field is a facet item in SXA, so we are limited to what we can do about this.

Is there a way to configure this in SXA 1.4?

Answer (score 2):

There is a default date format in a code and in certain criteria logic should use the format from this setting

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.DateFormat" value="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"/>
```

file: `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Solr.config.disabled`

If for some reason it is not taken into account and you can see that queries in `Search.log.*.txt` files still use Lucene format then please contact Sitecore support.

To help them, you can mention following information:

```
Description: Search results are not filtered correctly by date range.
Hotfix ID: 11697-1
```

Comment: Thanks @Alan, yes the format in the XA's Solr override is not being taken into account. I get ["Invalid Date String:'20180301'"]. I'll contact Sitecore Support. Thanks again